# Extract density estimation for different groups

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, unique, kernel-density

I have a data frame (df) that looks like this:

```
> summary(df)
   Occurence        Group          
 Min.   :0.001   Length:7990       
 1st Qu.:0.028   Class :character  
 Median :0.160   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :0.195                     
 3rd Qu.:0.307                     
 Max.   :0.600                     
 NA's   :5473

> unique(df$Group)
 [1] "fa20,0"   "sa20,0"   "fa05,0"   "sa10,0"   "flatsa,0" "flatfa,0" "fa10,0"   "sa05,0"   "flatsa,1" "fa10,1"   "fa05,1"   "sa20,1"   "flatfa,1" "fa20,1"   "sa10,1"   "sa05,1"
```

I am trying to get a kernel density estimation of occurence by each unique Group witht he density() function. I am able to do it one group at a time:

```
> flatsa <- density(c(as.numeric(ag04_pattern_long$Occurence[ag04_pattern_long$Group == "flatsa,0"])), na.rm=T)

> flatsa_df2 <- enframe(flatsa$x, value = "X") %>%
+     add_column(Y=flatsa$y) %>%
+     add_column(Group = "flatsa,0") %>%
+     select(-name)
```

Which produces this output for flatsa_df2:

```
# A tibble: 512 x 3
        X       Y Group   
    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   
 1 -0.168 0.00317 flatsa,0
 2 -0.166 0.00351 flatsa,0
 3 -0.164 0.00387 flatsa,0
 4 -0.162 0.00427 flatsa,0
 5 -0.161 0.00471 flatsa,0
 6 -0.159 0.00519 flatsa,0
 7 -0.157 0.00570 flatsa,0
 8 -0.155 0.00628 flatsa,0
 9 -0.153 0.00689 flatsa,0
10 -0.151 0.00755 flatsa,0
# ... with 502 more rows
```

How can I do this for all 16 unique elements in df$Group at once? Ideally they will all go into one single dataframe. I have tried:

```
dens_table <- setDT(ag04_pattern_long)[, .(dens=density(ag04_pattern_long$Occurence, na.rm=T)), by = Group]

for(i in length(unique(ag04_pattern_long$Group))){
  dens_table <- density(c(as.numeric(ag04_pattern_long$Occurence[i], na.rm=T)))
}
```

But none of those produce the correct output. The loops gives me an error, saying that it needs "at least 2 points to select a bandwidth". I think this indicates that it does not take all df$Occurence values for each unique(df$Group) into account .

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `base` R method:

```
occur_list = split(df$Occurrence, df$Group)
est_list = lapply(df_list, function(x) {
  data.frame(density(x, na.rm=T)[c("x", "y")])
})
results = do.call(rbind, est_list)
results$Group = rep(names(occur_list), each = sapply(est_list, nrow))
```

We could also use a `for` loop, adapting your attempt:

```
results = list()
for(i in unique(ag04_pattern_long$Group)){
  results[[i]] <- data.frame(density(ag04_pattern_long$Occurence[ag0f_pattern_long$Group == i], na.rm = T)[c("x", "y")])
  results[[i]]$Group = i
}
results = do.call(rbind, results)
```

Or using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  nest_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(dens = list(data.frame(density(data$Occurrence)[c("x", "y")]))) %>%
  select(-data) %>%
  unnest(cols = dens)
```

In all cases I've removed the `c(as.numeric())` from inside the loop. Make sure the entire `Occurrence` column is numeric before looping - that is better than converting each piece of the column inside the loop.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear1 If you consider the problem resolved, please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it in the left margin.